# Collect all rows for specific column values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so

```
c_id code b_id    
1   A    32    
1   B    9    
1   C    25  
1   C    99
2   A    33   
2   B    11
```

I would like to collect all occurances of column b_id for each c_id segregated by code. So in this case I would like to have the result:

1 : A : 32
1 : B : 9
1 : C : 25,99
2 : A : 33
2 : B : 11
1 : C : 25
Is this possible in pandas ?

Comment: @jezrael Wrong dupe marked. Please check the Expected output.

Comment: Do you think no `:` ?

Comment: @jezrael I'm just trying to simplify the expected output so it is easier to read, there is not `:` delimiter in the table itself. I am unsure as to how the output will look so I added `:`. Plus this has more complexity than the question pointed to

Comment: @jezrael No. I am not talking about the delimiter. OP does not want to groupby across the entire column. He wants to groupby on repeated values.

Comment: Why is last `1 : C : 25` ?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - It is same, only last row is problematic, so cannot be dupe `df = df.astype(str).groupby(['c_id','code'])['b_id'].agg(','.join)`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.cat(sep=':'), axis=1)

0    1:A:32
1     1:B:9
2    1:C:25
3    1:C:99
4    2:A:33
5    2:B:11
```